# Discovering plus patterns in 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, traversal

I'm not looking for a solution. All I'm looking for is guidance. I am stuck on this problem and I have no idea what to study or learn in order to solve it. I tried many solutions but they all have bugs. Please take a look.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV89G.jpg)

Translation:

- Given a matrix N x M
- 2 <= N <= 15
- 2 <= M <= 15

Every cell has either a 1 or 0. The user shall check if a plus symbol forms from the connected cells with value of 1. The segments that form the plus have same length and are perpendicular to one other, cutting in the middle. Write a program that shows have many valid pluses there are and the number of [1] cells inside the pluses.

The figure shows a correct plus and an incorrect plus.

I kindly ask that you show me some way to go about cracking this problem, some lesson to learn or some algorithm to read. Thank you! My code trying this problem is below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int column = 8; // this is N
    int row = 8; // this is M
    int pluses = 0;
    int addition = 1;
    int ones = 0;
    bool could_be_plus = true;

    int example[row][column];
    cout << "Place values [0] or [1]\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
            cin >> example[i][j];
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < row - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < column - 1; ++j) {
            could_be_plus = true;
            while (could_be_plus) {
                //addition variable controls the number of layer outside first plus
                if (example[i][j - addition] == 1 && example[i - addition][j] == 1 && example[i + addition][j] == 1 && example[i][j + addition] == 1) {
                    if (addition == 1) {
                        pluses++;
                        //including the center there are 5 ones
                        ones += 5;
                        addition++;
                    }
                    else {
                        ones += 4;
                        addition++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    could_be_plus = false;
                    addition = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "pluses: " << pluses << endl;
    cout << "number of 1s: " << ones << endl;
};
```

My code had bugs that I couldn't fix regarding [1] cells (not part of the plus) that were touching the plus cells.

Answer (score 0):

The needed algorithm is not so complicated. But, the solution needs a lot of typing work.

We iterate over each cell in the matrix. If a cell is '1' then it is a potential middle point of a cross and we can evaluate further.

We look in all 4 directions of the current cell in the matrix, starting from the current cell. Of course maximum until we hit the border of the matrix.

We count the number of '1's beneath the current cell.

Then, after we have counted all '1's, we check all counts for all directions.

According to the definition, they must be equal and greater than 0. In the drawing, where the lower wing of the potential cross is longer, it is deemed to be invalid.

There are really many potential soultions. I prepared one for you. Maybe you can then understand the algorithm better.

Please check:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int main() {

#define GET_USER_INPUT 0
#if GET_USER_INPUT

    // This will define the extension of the 2d matrix
    std::size_t numberOfRows{}, numberOfColumns{};

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Inform the user what to do and try to get the correct input
    bool validInput{};
    while (not validInput) {
        std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter number of rows and number of columns for the matrix.\n"
            "Condition: rows and columns are greater 1 and smaller than 16:\n";
        // Try to read values
        std::cin >>  numberOfRows >> numberOfColumns;
        // Chekc, if the input operation worked (nobody entered abc or similar)
        if (not std::cin) {
            std::cout << "\n\n*** Error: Invalid input format. Please try again\n\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        }
        else {
            // Check bounds
            if ((numberOfRows > 1) and (numberOfRows < 16) and (numberOfColumns > 1) and (numberOfColumns < 16))
                validInput = true;
            else
                std::cout << "\n\n*** Error: Values are out of bounds. Please try again\n\n";
        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define and initialize a 2d vector
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(numberOfRows, std::vector<char>(numberOfColumns,'-'));
    // Just for display purposes, we want to have a copy of the matrix 
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> tmp(numberOfRows, std::vector<char>(numberOfColumns, '-'));

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Fill the matrix
    for (std::size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (std::size_t col{}; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            validInput = false;
            while (not validInput) {
                std::cout << "\nEnter 1 or 0 for row '" << row + 1 << "' and column '" << col+1 << "': ";
                if (std::cin >> matrix[row][col]) {
                    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    if ((matrix[row][col] == '0') or (matrix[row][col] == '1')) {
                        std::cout << "\n\nCurrent matrix:\n";
                        for (std::size_t i{}; i < numberOfRows; ++i) {
                            for (std::size_t k{}; k < numberOfColumns; ++k) std::cout << matrix[i][k] << ' ';
                            std::cout << '\n';
                        }
                        std::cout << '\n';
                        validInput = true;
                    }
                    else
                        std::cout << "\n\n*** Error: Wrong input. Only '1 or '0' allowed, try again\n\n";
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "\n\n*** Error: Wrong input characters, try again\n\n";
                    std::cin.clear();
                    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                }
            }
        }
    }
#else
    // Used predefine matrix
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define and initialize a 2d vector
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix{
        {'0','1','0','0','0'},
        {'1','1','1','0','0'},
        {'0','1','0','1','0'},
        {'0','0','1','1','1'},
        {'0','1','0','1','0'},
        {'0','1','0','1','0'},
        {'1','1','1','0','0'},
        {'0','1','0','0','0'},
        {'0','1','0','0','0'},
    };
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> tmp = matrix;
    std::size_t numberOfRows = matrix.size();
    std::size_t numberOfColumns = matrix.front().size();

#endif


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Lambdas to count the 1s beneath a given position
    auto longestExtendRight = [&](std::size_t row, std::size_t col) -> unsigned {
        unsigned counter{};
        tmp[row][col] = '+';
        while (col < numberOfColumns - 1) {
            ++col;
            if (tmp[row][col] == '1') {
                tmp[row][col] = '+';
                ++counter;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return counter;
    };
    auto longestExtendLeft = [&](std::size_t row, std::size_t col) -> unsigned {
        unsigned counter{};
        tmp[row][col] = '+';
        while (col > 0) {
            --col;
            if (tmp[row][col] == '1') {
                tmp[row][col] = '+';
                ++counter;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return counter;
    };
    auto longestExtendDown = [&](std::size_t row, std::size_t col) -> unsigned {
        unsigned counter{};
        tmp[row][col] = '+';
        while (row < numberOfRows - 1) {
            ++row;
            if (tmp[row][col] == '1') {
                tmp[row][col] = '+';
                ++counter;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return counter;
    };
    auto longestExtendUp = [&](std::size_t row, std::size_t col) -> unsigned {
        unsigned counter{};
        tmp[row][col] = '+';
        while (row > 0) {
            --row;
            if (tmp[row][col] == '1') {
                tmp[row][col] = '+';
                ++counter;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return counter;
    };
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Now check each cell of the matrix, if there are the same numbers of 1 around

    // Show matrix again:
    std::cout << "\n\n\nMatrix:\n\n";
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < numberOfRows; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t k{}; k < numberOfColumns; ++k) std::cout << matrix[i][k] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for (std::size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (std::size_t col{}; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {

            // Only with a 1 in the middle
            if (matrix[row][col] == '1') {
                // Make a copy of the current matrix
                tmp = matrix;

                // Check for a cross
                const unsigned extendRight = longestExtendRight(row, col);
                const unsigned extendLeft = longestExtendLeft(row, col);
                const unsigned extendDown = longestExtendDown(row, col);
                const unsigned extendUp = longestExtendUp(row, col);

                if ((extendRight == extendLeft) and (extendLeft == extendDown) and (extendDown == extendUp) and (extendRight > 0)) {

                    // Corss found. Show it
                    std::cout << "\n\nCross found:\n";
                    for (std::size_t i{}; i < numberOfRows; ++i) {
                        for (std::size_t k{}; k < numberOfColumns; ++k) std::cout << tmp[i][k] << ' ';
                        std::cout << '\n';
                    }
                    std::cout << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is great for detecting crosses that have longer sections, but how would I go about ignoring crosses that have a '1' cell directly diagonal to my cross middle point, or even a '1' cell horizontal to a line of vertical '1' cells. Simply, how to be sure that every cell all around my cross is a '0'. I ask of my own curiosity.